# How to change domain of API App on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps

I created an API app for MS Azure, but it runs on url like: https://microsoft-apiapped89163604714d21b7e4a3424ed82d50.azurewebsites.net/...

Can I switch it to my own domain name somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but unfortunately there is currently a limitation that will prevent the API App from working properly. There is a list of known limitations and issue which you can find [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/7f8b42f2-ac0d-48b8-a35e-3b4934e1c25e/api-app-known-issues?forum=AzureAPIApps). The fix will be available quite soon but I don't have a specific ETA to share.

Once this is fixed, you can customize the domain by:

1. Going to the API App blade.
2. On the blade, find the "API App host" property on the Essentials and click it.
3. This will open the API App host blade. Click on "Settings" from the toolbar on the top.

   4. Then find the "Custom domains and SSL" setting and customize the domain.

Effectively, once you're done with Step 2, you can follow the guide of Customizing the domain of a Web App, as both API Apps and Web Apps share the same underlying infrastructure. The guide is available [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/)

Hope it helps.